# I keep getting "error: cannot find symbol" message while trying to put responses

Tags: cannot-find-symbol

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Outside{
 public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Is your homework done? ");
    String homework;
    homework = scan.nextLine();
    String answer1;
  answer1 = No||no||NO||No ||no ||NO ;
    if (homework.equals(answer1)){
        System.out.print("Do your homework");
    }//If Homework
 }//main
}//outside
```

I'm getting an error at the No||...||NO ; section. What I'm currently trying to do is make it say "Do your homework" if it gets any "no" response. I tried using if (homework.equals(No||...||NO)) and it gives the same error. What statement should I use?

Comment: Also, there is no need it declare and initialize your variables on different lines. `String homework = scan.nextLine();` works just fine

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `answer1` is a string. Strings can only hold a sequence of characters... nothing else. If you want to capture the idea that it could be one of a few different strings, you will need to use a different data structure.

### Option 1: list of strings

The option that is most in the spirit of what you are asking is this:

```java
List<String> negativeAnswers = Arrays.asList("No", "no", "NO", "No ", "no ", "NO ");
if (negativeAnswers.contains(homework)) {
    // homework was one of the negative answers
}
```

### Option 2: case-independent comparison

The better option for this particular case is just to ignore capitalization and spaces when you are doing your comparison.

```java
if (homework.toLowerCase().strip().equals("no") {
    // homework was similar to "no"
}
```

`toLowerCase()` converts the string to all lowercase and `strip()` removes all the whitespace. If you are using an old version of Java, you will have to use `trim()` instead.

Comment: I'll definitely keep this for later use, but I'm currently in a CS class.

Within the class (https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_operators.asp using this as a reference on where my class is at) I'm up to if..else + while (My class also learned of import). We haven't started to using the terms your recommending and would likely affect my grade with this assignment

Comment: Thank you for showing me these new statements to use, I'll definitely keep them in mind

Comment: If you just want to use basic if..else, then you could do something like `if (homework.equals("no") || homework.equals("NO") || homework.equals("No") ... )` etc